# Would Ireland qualify for the 2019 Cricket World Cup if their game against Afghanistan ended in a tie?

Tags: rules, cricket, tie-breaker, cricket-world-cup

The BBC website seems to say that Zimbabwe would qualify instead of Ireland, but surely if it was a tie, it would go down to net run rate between the two teams?

[A BBC results table here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/world-cup-qualifier/table) indicates that Ireland has a superior net run rate to Zimbabwe and a tie would take them level on points.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75007/discussion-on-question-by-austeretiger-would-ireland-qualify-for-the-2019-cricke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained by [Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8038/report/1133029/zimbabwe-vs-united-arab-emirates-32nd-match-super-sixes-world-cup-qualifier):

> In that case, all three teams will be tied on five points each but both Afghanistan's and Ireland's net run rate will take a beating since the teams will be conceding as many runs as they score. While Afghanistan's NRR (0.34) is already below Zimbabwe's (0.42), Ireland's NRR (0.47) will slip below Zimbabwe's to a value of 0.377.

The point is that a tie does affect your net run rate in that it pulls in back towards zero. Consider a hypothetical example where a team has played one match, scored 200 in its 50 overs and conceded only 100. Their net run rate is now (200 - 100) / 50 = 2.00. Now add in a tie where both teams score 150 (doesn't actually matter what the score is): the net run rate is now ((200 + 150) - (100 + 150)) / 100 = 1.00; while the absolute difference in the number of runs has not changed (that's the definition of a tie!), the number of overs being considered has increased, so the net run rate always has a smaller magnitude after the tie than before.

As Cricinfo point out, the situation is different if the match is abandoned as that Ireland's run rate does not change.